# Is there a python function to rename an object's attribute?

Tags: python

Basically, is there already a built-in or commonly available function that does this:

```
def rename_attribute(object_, old_attribute_name, new_attribute_name):
    setattr(object_, new_attribute_name, getattr(object_, old_attribute_name))
    delattr(object_, old_attribute_name)
```

Comment: I haven't heard of one, after looking over the magic methods in the docs.

Comment: Objects in Python are little more than glorified namespaces. Would it make sense to have a function for renaming variables? If you need this perhaps you should be storing your data in a dict-like structure instead of an object.

Comment: Good question... maybe?  This is not exactly the same, but there might be something akin to how swapping two variables can naturally be done in one line because of the way python works.

Comment: I think there are multiple factors that help decide whether I should be using a dict-like structure, and this one is less pressing because I can just create the rename_attribute function.

Comment: While possible, why would you want/need to do this? Semantically, all instances of the same class should share the same attributes; it's the *values* of the attributes that differentiate the instances, not what attributes are available. Changing the name of an attribute breaks that relationship between an object and its class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no builtin or standard library function doing this. I assume, because:

- it is trivial, as your completely sufficient example shows
- there's no general use case

Answer (score 19):

No, there isn't but you could make it *easier* playing with the namespace:

```
def rename_attribute(obj, old_name, new_name):
    obj.__dict__[new_name] = obj.__dict__.pop(old_name)
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to use the [*Setter* and *Getter* bult-in python's methods](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/property-getters-setters) to provide a facade / rename for the original attribute.

For instance: suppose you have an attribute `attr` and you want to rename it to `new_attr` in order to return or modify `attr` when you refer to  `new_attr`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.attr = a
        
    @property
    def new_attr(self):
        return self.attr
        
    @new_attr.setter
    def new_attr(self, new_value):
        self.attr = new_value
```

When calling the the attribute for its new name, we have:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo(2)
    print('The renamed attribute is', f.new_attr)
    f.new_attr = 5
    print('The renamed attribute after using setter method is', f.new_attr)
    print('The old attribute is', f.attr)
```

At the output:

```
'The renamed attribute is 2'
'The renamed attribute after using setter method is 5'
'The old attribute is 5'
```

> Notice that `attr` always still available for its use and `new_attr` always will make reference to `attr`.